# Something better than the standard library for c# Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I know and use the standard c# regex library, and I love it. It does pretty much everything I want (except, may be, reverse matching).

However, lately I was wondering - is there something else for .Net out there, having features that I never knew I needed until I'll see them.

Does anybody know of any good regex libraries (preferably open source) for .Net, which would let me do much more than the standard library can?

Comment: Define "much more than the standard library", and you might have a question on your hands :)

Comment: I think there is only a very few modern libraries for regex. Even though many languages make regex available, most just wrap lib calls to them. And though they are probably open source, most don't stray from a base style (like pcre). Perl and .NET are very robust. Other than language integration, for now I think future enhancements will probably need standards for compatability. Of course, there is that Unicode problem that looms large.

Comment: Yeah, some specific features would help this question a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching and Regular expressions are a pretty well defined, mature problem, and happily .Net has a well implemented solution.

However, if you're curious about different, more domain specific ways of searching there's always the jQuery-like fizzler or sharp-query for searching html.  And there's always XPath & Linq to xml for xml.

Otherwise, Regex is pretty great IMO.